# WCF hosting: Can access svc file but cannot go to wsdl link

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF service that is hosted in IIS 7.5.
I have two servers, one for test and one for production.

The service works fine on test server, but on the production server I have the following error.

When I access the address `http://..../service.svc` I can see the default page that says:

---

You have created a service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

```
svcutil.exe http://..../service.svc?wsdl
```

This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use the generated client class to call the Service.

---

But when I click the wsdl link, I cannot go to the wsdl page. It returns me to this default web page without any errors. I am suspecting a network/firewall authorization error but does anybody have an experience like this one?

All IIS settings are the same for test and production servers.

Thank you, Best Regards.

Comment: do you have a mex endpoint configured?

Comment: Do you have some kind of router/load-balancer in front of your service to introduce redirection problems?

Comment: Yep I use load balancers, and my recent research showed me that these load balancers are the origin of my problems. Thank you for your responses guys.

Comment: @SelcukSasoglu hi, I'm having this same issue. Did you have to change any configuration in the load balancers?

Comment: @DaniloRuziska yes, as I said, I had to change a setting on the load balancer, but as you can imagine after 9 years I do not remember what I have changed anymore. Sorry. Try redirecting only one server from the load balancer first, see if it works. This way you might find a setting difference between your servers.

Answer (score 25):

had the same problem. i fixed it by adding httpsGetEnabled to serviceBehaviors>behavior like this:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

maybe it helps someone else. dont think that u need this hint after 4years =)

Comment: I can't upvote this enough. My issue was I had many services with working WSDLs but one without. The one that didn't work needed to be "http**s**GetEnabled" (with the "s") instead of just "httpGetEnabled".

Answer (score 18):

You basically need three things to enable browsing to your WSDL for a WCF service:

1. a service behavior which enables service metadata
2. set the httpGetEnabled=True on that service metadata behavior to allow http browsing to that metadata
3. a mex endpoint on your service

So your config on the server side might looks something like this (plus a bit more stuff):

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior" name="YourService">
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IYourService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Points 1 and 2 are handled by this line here:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

You need to reference that service behavior in your `<service>` tag for it to become active.

Point 3 (MEX endpoint) is this section here:

```
<endpoint address="mex" 
          binding="mexHttpBinding" 
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

For http, use the `mexHttpBinding`, and the `IMetadataExchange` contract is a WCF system contract for metadata exchange .

Comment: I agree. 
All these configurations were correctly set.

I forgot to mention an important detail: the service works fine on my test server, but this error came up when I deployed the service to my production server. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

I know that answer it's so late but I had the same problem and the solution was:

Add tags `[ServiceContract]` and `[OperationContract]` on interface that it is implemented on service `.svc`. Visual Studio create interface when you select `WCF Service` but I deleted the interface and I created my own interface.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();
}
```

I hope to help somebody.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the issue is with publishing metadata. Just adding one more tips. You can also add service meta data using code, like this :

```
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;

host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
```

More details here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738489%28v=vs.110%29.aspx