# WCF service working but wsdl file not opening in only in PROD

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, wsdl

I have followed multiple questions here on stack over flow which suggest httpsGetEnabled in web.config and adding ServiceContract in code. But none of them are helping me.

**My issue is only for my PROD environment. For QA enviornment I'm able to browse wsdl file.**

Note : For PROD, other systems are able to consume my service and able to transfer data but I'm unable to browse wsdl file.

**Tech Stack :** It's .NET Framework 4.7 hosted on IIS 10.0.14393.0

Posting both QA and PROD config files.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DevMode" value="QA" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- My con string here -->
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.7" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="200000000" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000" />
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\logs\Traces.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

PROD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DevMode" value="PROD" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
   <!-- My con string here -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.7" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="200000000" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000" />
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\logs\Traces.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you referred to this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100426/wcf-hosting-can-access-svc-file-but-cannot-go-to-wsdl-link

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that your service endpoint isnt linked to your behavior